# Edit the URL of a bookmark in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, bookmarks

[This page](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/bookmarks-firefox#w_how-do-i-change-the-name-or-location-of-a-bookmark) on the Mozilla site shows how edit the title, folder, and tags of a bookmark. But not the URL?!

[image]
<sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://user-media-prod-cdn.itsre-sumo.mozilla.net/uploads/gallery/images/2018-11-16-15-51-54-b05bd5.png))</sub>

Is there a way to tweak the URL of a bookmark?

I miss the easy spreadsheet-style of listing and editing bookmarks provided by the Safari browser.

Answer (score 2):

1. Right click on the bookmark entry you want to change.
2. Select `Properties`

[image]

3. Modify the URL of the bookmark in question then click `Save`:

[image]

Comment: Do it through the "Show all bookmarks" menu. Command + Shift + B.

Comment: Neither of these approaches is feasible if you have lots (hundreds or thousands) of bookmarks: it's quite frustrating that the change can't be made while the bookmark is in front of the users. I'm hoping that there might be an extension that'll cover it, but I don't know of one.

Comment: Actually, a bookmark can be added through the Bookmark Library (as opposed to using the "star" icon next to the URL) by going to Organize->New Bookmark. A custom URL can then be entered. Horribly unintuitive? Absolutely. Usable? Yes.