# Edit bookmark URL from the Edit bookmark menu?

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, css

In the menu that is opened by clicking on the blue star icon that appears near your URL bar when you have a page bookmarked, there is no option to edit the URL of said bookmark. This is annoying when you only wish to make a minor change to the bookmark, such as changing example.com/page-1 to example.com/page-2. Is there any way to make this menu display the URL of your bookmark? I feel like Firefox used to be able to do this in much older versions.

[image: The menu in question]

I had hoped that a userChrome.css fix would do the trick. I found the below online, but it seems to have had no effect.

```
/* Add option to edit bookmark URLs under blue star menu */
#editBMPanel_locationRow, #editBMPanel_keywordRow {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

[This question](https://superuser.com/q/1509081/865660) expresses a similar frustration, but does not insist on modifying the menu that I've screenshotted above. I only want solutions that modify said menu.

It appears that my current userChrome.css file may be of relevance. Here it is

```
/*@namespace url("http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul");*/
@namespace xul "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
@namespace html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";
.bookmark-item{
    margin-left: 0 !important;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
    padding-left: 0 !important; 
}
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: none !important;
}
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item .toolbarbutton-icon{
    margin-left: 2px !important;
}
#PlacesToolbarItems > .bookmark-item > .toolbarbutton-icon[label]:not([label=""]) {
    margin-inline-end: 2px !important;
}
toolbarbutton.subviewbutton.subviewbutton-iconic .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
/* --- [1] --- */
toolbarbutton.bookmark-item:hover:not(.subviewbutton):not([disabled="true"]):not([open]) .toolbarbutton-text{
    display: -moz-box !important;
}
/* Hide Giant Thumbnail and Favicon */
#editBookmarkPanelImage,
*|div#editBookmarkPanelFaviconContainer {
  display: none !important;
}

/* fix right click menu disappearing on highlighted text */
*#contentAreaContextMenu { margin: 12px 0 0 12px };

/* Add option to edit bookmark URLs under blue star menu */
#editBMPanel_locationRow, #editBMPanel_keywordRow {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Works for me (on latest FF 98.0.2).

Are you sure you put the *userChrome.css* file to the right place, in a folder called "chrome" inside your profile folder. Note that the "chrome" folder does not exist in default installations, it's only used for customization, so you must create it.

For example:
`C:\Users\YYYY\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\XXXXXXXX.default\chrome\userChrome.css`

You can find the correct folder by typing `about:support` in your URL bar and clicking "Open Folder" under the "Profile Folder" category.

You probably also need to have the xul and html tags in the file, like this:

```css
/* userChrome.css */

@namespace xul "http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul";
@namespace html "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

/* Add option to edit bookmark URLs under blue star menu */
#editBMPanel_locationRow {
  visibility: visible !important;
}
```

You also need to set the configuration option
`toolkit.legacyUserProfileCustomizations.stylesheets` = true
in about:config to allow userChrome.css to function.

---

**Or** just extract this zip file to your profile folder: https://gist.github.com/anzz1/980102da101505b8bc03e46d54f778fe/archive/3ab4d55882bd0b72828c9d3c880bb7b6ba387cbb.zip

It contains the *userChrome.css* style file and *user.js* to set the config option for you.

---

**EDIT**
I forgot about the last part, which *should* fix the problem of configuration not applying. After applying userChrome.css and user.js, go to `about:support` and select "Clear Startup Cache" option. After that, restart your Firefox **twice**.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas then, as it works fine for me... Maybe nuke the whole profile and do a clean reinstall? Tbh that is indeed a nuclear option. If you want to troubleshoot instead, I would start by searching for any random theme which uses a userChrome.css and trying that, to see whether the problem is that if userChrome.css style gets applied at all or is it something else.

Comment: You're on to something. Replacing my current userChrome.css with yours makes your modifications work. There's clearly something in my original file (see the question) that's incompatible with yours.